# Two instances of an SPFx web part that use some simple JavaScript code are failing ... How do I find the web part ID?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I have written a simple SPFx web part that uses JavaScript to show and hide items from a list using JavaScript.

I use code like this ....

```
document.getElementById("a-" + rowNum).style.display = "none";
```

This works fine.

However if I place a second instance of the web part on the page it doesn't work.

This is because there are now two instances of the tag "a-1" "a-2" etc.
I need a way to distinguish the exact web part.

Is there a way to get the web part ID?

I was going to just put a random number into the tag to identify it but it seems like there should be a better way.

Thanks
P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web part will not be good fit for hiding and showing the item based some custom logic in SharePoint list.

SPFx does not work like earlier SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering.

There are two approach for customizing the SharePoint list.

1. SPFx Field Customizer in case of if you want some customization
   based on JavaScript.

   - Refer this Microsoft Docs for SPFx Field Customizer: [Build a sample field Customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer)
2. Use conditional column formatting /JSON Formatting

   - Refer this Microsoft Docs for JSON formatting: [Column Formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

The unique ID of your web part instance can be accessed through the web part's context object: `this.context.instanceId`.
It should be unique for each instance of a web part on a page (or across pages as well).

Another way to give your list items a unique ID is by generating a unique ID using the `getId(prefix?:string)` method that comes with Fluent UI (fka UI Fabric). https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/utilities?view=office-ui-fabric-react-latest#@fluentui-utilities-getid-function(1)